# jQuery under SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is there any way I can run jQuery under SVG instead of HTML?

I know about [jQuery svg plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/svg) but this is not what I want.

As for now the jQuery engine contains some statements like this:

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.display = "none";
```

It fails with exception during jQuery initialization under SVG because SVG document is unable to create `div` element. And there are some other HTML-specific places in jQuery which fail in unpredictable places under SVG.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hacked an old version of jquery around a bit, and it is possible to run it in svg-only mode with some modifications. Feel free to take the changes and do whatever you want with them. [Here's a demo](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/jquery/jqueryanim.svg) and here's [the modified jquery sourcecode](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/jquery/jquery131.js).

It's incomplete and probably has some issues if you want to use it in both HTML and SVG, but it's a start, and works to some extent at least.

Comment: There was one more issue with classes of elements. Class selectors and methods didn't work because in HTML elem.className is a string but in SVG it is an object. String class is taken from elem.className.baseVal. I have patched newest (1.4.2) version of jQuery. One more issue is that SVG doesn't call initialization methods so I introduce jQueryInitialize and call it in onload. Here is a link: http://hgcoaxial.appspot.com/static/jquery-1.4.2.svg.js to the patched jQuery. And here is more sophisticated example: http://hgcoaxial.appspot.com/static/jquery-1.4.2.svg.js of jQuery under SVG.

Comment: Thanks, almost works, only - how do I animate e.g. position of a circle? jQuery works with CSS attribs, and circle's `cx` / `cy` has no CSS counterpart IIUC. I've tried `top` but no effect (although does not throw).

Comment: @Volodymyr, thanks for the link. Do you plan on keeping this updated? I have real use for this and would love to see it become official.

Comment: @zourtney, thanks for feedback. Yes, I think about making it official, and keep it updated. But I relay need help on this, I don't have enough time to make it alone.